# How to schedule at particular time service in android

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am making demo android project in which I want to schedule service daily at 8:00 clock. I am calling this method from my launcher activity. Whenever I start application then below method is called then at the same time it start service and display notification. I only want it should schedule in such a way it should execute at 8:00 instead of everytime I open app.

```
public static void scheduleVerseNotificationService(Context mContext) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Notification.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, intent, 0);

    // Set the alarm to start at approximately 08:00 morning.
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you schedule timer for time which is already passed so it is called as soon you request `alarmManager.setInexactRepeating`

Here is code to fix your issue:

```
public static void scheduleVerseNotificationService(Context mContext) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Notification.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(mContext, 0, intent, 0);

    // reset previous pending intent
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);

    // Set the alarm to start at approximately 08:00 morning.
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    // if the scheduler date is passed, move scheduler time to tomorrow
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() > calendar.getTimeInMillis()) {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    }

    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble understanding your questions so:

```
 I only want it should schedule in such a way it should execute at 8:00 instead of everytime I open app.
```

I understood that as "I only want to execute an Activity at 8:00, and not when I start that Activity"
So, a suggestion is:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Intent YOUR_INTENT = getIntent();
if (YOUR_INTENT!= null) {
 if(YOUR_INTENT.getStringExtra("YOUR_PACKAGE.A_VAR_NAME") != null){
  if (YOUR_INTENT.getStringExtra("YOUR_PACKAGE.A_VAR_NAME").equals("A VALUE")) {
   DO_THE_CODE_YOU_WANT();
  }
}
```

Then, on your intent, you add a value: `intent.putExtra("YOUR_PACKAGE.A_VAR_NAME", "A VALUE");`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this line for pendingIntent

```
pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0, intent, 0);
```